How to prevent Android app from reverting to previous build?
I'm working on an android app. I'm using Jetpack compose and Kotlin and it is debug build. The issue is that if I install a version from android studio to my physical device using USB debugging, then it works correctly. But, when I clear app storage/data from phone settings, my app automatically reverts back to older look and behaviour out of nowhere. Note that I didn't install/uninstall the app. It was only on my phone. And there is no connection with android studio. It's very frustrating. Please give me the solution.
I tried uninstalling and then installing from Android Studio, then it works fine, current build is loaded. But, then again if I'll clear app data from settings, it'll revert back out of nowhere.

Try changing the value of tag allowBackup from true to false in your app's AndroidManifest.xml.
<application
    android:allowBackup="false">
</application>


Still didn't work

Wipe app data then uninstall app, and reinstall it.

Issue still persists

Execute adb shell pm list packages | grep <your package name> on Terminal to check if there are one more outputs. If so, maybe a different flavor? Or you might debug your app in instant run mode? If so, you have to disable this feature to avoid some incoming unexpected issues.
